# Javascript (jQuery) filter table multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I'm creating a filter that will search a model number for specific characters at specific locations.

jsFiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/yqevU/2/

Excuse the messy code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var txt, myval, loc, chk, x, z, modeltxt, mychar1, mychar2, modelchar1, modelchar2;

$('.sx').blur(function() {
    $('.sx').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != '') {

          if ($(this).hasClass('x1')) {
               loc = $(this).attr('data-val');
               myval = $(this).val();
              $('table.TF td:nth-child(2)').each(function() {
                    txt = $(this).text();
                    chk = txt.charAt(loc);                        
                    if (myval != chk) {
                        $(this).parent().hide();
                    } else {
                        $(this).parent().show();
                    }
                });
            } else {}


          if ($(this).hasClass('x2')) {
              loc = parseInt($(this).attr('data-val'));
              z = $(this).attr('data-tag');
              myval = $(this).val();
            $('table.TF td:nth-child(2)').each(function() {
                modeltxt = $(this).text();
                mychar1 = myval.substring(0,1);
                mychar2 = myval.slice(-1);
                modelchar1 = modeltxt.charAt(loc);
                modelchar2 = modeltxt.charAt(loc + 1);

              if (mychar1 == modelchar1 && mychar2 == modelchar2) {
                 $(this).parent().show();
              } else {
                $(this).parent().hide();
              }
            });

          } else {}



        } else {}
     });
});


});
```

Try typing "K" into ITEM #13. The filter will then only display the Model Numbers with the "K" at that specific location.

Now notice some of the models have a "G" or "E" at ITEM #10 - So try typing a "G" into the box ITEM #10. The script does nothing. Whereas I need it to only display the models with a "G" at ITEM #10 and a "K" at ITEM #13

I want the script to continue narrowing down the model numbers each time the user makes a new input

---

**EDIT**

FYI, the external script I attached converts the table into a class with "TF", thats where that comes from

---

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Sorry guys.

All I had to do was remove these two lines:

```
$(this).parent().show();
```

Then the script works.